# Data's getters able to watch non-reactive localStorage, but not for computed?

Tags: vue.js, reactive, computed-properties

I have a section that shows a `Login` button when there a user is not authenticated(as shown in localStorage), otherwise `username` and a 'logout botton' will be shown.

The code works when I put the `authenticated` inside the `data` block. However, if I put it in the `computed` field, it always shows `login`

```
#template
          <router-link v-if="!authenticated" to="login">Log In</router-link>
          <template v-else>
            Logged in as {{username}}
            <button @click="logout">Log out</button>
          </template>
```

```
#script
    data: function() {
      return {
        // get authenticated() {  //this works
        //   return localStorage.getItem('authenticated');
        // },
      }
    },
    computed: function() {
      return {
        authenticated: function() {  //this does not work
          return localStorage.getItem('authenticated');
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue isn't able to observe changes to local storage items, and so the `authenticated` computed property will forever return the same value because Vue caches the values of computed properties.

In this scenario you would typically use a method:

```es6
methods: {
  authenticated() {
    return localStorage.getItem('authenticated')
  }
}
```

although your getter would work too.

Comment: This doesn't work either... p.s. the `Login` part is in the header part of a single page application

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Are you calling it like a method: `authenticated()`?

Comment: It's work now. I may have forgotten to save it when I ran it earlier today. Can you also explains why `data` and `methods` work and why `computed` don't?

Comment: Because Vue caches the result of the computed property and won't re-evaluate its value on subsequent accesses unless it detects that some dependent data has changed, but this won't ever happen because local storage is not observable by Vue. A getter that you defined in `data` or a method won't be cached by Vue and will be executed each time the getter is accessed or the method is called.